# How can I change UINavigationController's rightBarButtonItem globally?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to change navigation bar's right item globally. So I created parent class like this:

```
@implementation ParentViewController
...
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"send"]];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sendImageView];

}
...
@end
```

And I have two `ViewController` classes named `A` and `B` that inherits from `ParentViewController`. Both of them has

```
- (void)loadView {
     [super loadView];
}
```

First instance of A comes out and performs

```
    B *vc = [[B alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The problem is that right bar button item appears only on A but not on B. I thought parent class's `loadView` getting called will do the trick but is not. How do I change that button globally?

I'm not using xib. So loadView always gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found some way to solve it. It changes right item as plain image and sets left item as back button with the title of "Back".

```
@implementation ParentViewController

- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    UIImageView *sendImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"send"]];
    sendImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sendImageView];

    //don't need the original back button
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back)];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem configureFlatButtonWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] highlightedColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] cornerRadius:5];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
        setTitleTextAttributes:@{
            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorFromHexCode:@"53a4db"],
     UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor],
     UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:15]
     } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)back {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

So if child class don't need to have back button it can `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`

Answer (score 1):

`loadView` won't be called if the view controller has an associated XIB as that will be used to load the view.

You might want to consider acting as the `delegate` of `UINavigationController` to handle this stuff and implementing `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`. You can then directly interrogate the new `viewController` to decide if you should do anything and, if required, you can change its `navigationItem`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post about this issue: http://www.codebestowed.com/ios-shared-barbuttonitems/

The basic idea is to subclass UINavigationController, give it a BarButtonItem property (self.myButton in the code below) and add code similar to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem) {
        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.myButton;
    }
}
```

For those interested, the blog post details how you can set this up further in InterfaceBuilder, which requires a bit of a hack (too much to go into in this answer).